# Different hierarchy

Tags: java, eclipse

The line of error is noted in the code below.  Something I notice is if I highlight the word Customer and hold down ctrl-T it brings up the hierarchy which shows Customer - SwimCalc which is right. But if I do the same with Contractor it says Contractor - SwimCalc.Customer

```
public class SwimCalc extends JFrame implements ActionListener { 
    private JTabbedPane jtabbedPane;  
    private JPanel Customers; 
    private JPanel Contractors;  
    private List<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<Customer>(); 

    // this fails 
    private List<Contractor> contractors = new ArrayList<Contractor>(); 

    JTextArea NameTextCustomers, ExistTextCustomers, MessageTextCustomers,  
    NameTextContractors, ExistTextContractors, MessageTextContractors; 
    JTextField lengthTextPool, widthTextPool, depthTextPool, volumeTextPool;  

    public SwimCalc() {  
        setTitle("Volume Calculator");  
        setSize (300, 200);  

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();  
        topPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );  
        getContentPane().add( topPanel );  

        createCustomers();  
        createContractors();  

        jtabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();  
        jtabbedPane.addTab("Customer", Customers);  
        topPanel.add(jtabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);  
    } 
}
```

Comment: So what's your question exactly?

Comment: Could you show us the definition of the `Contractor` class, and the exact error message you get here?

Comment: @Gareth: Error: Contractor cannot be resolved to a type.  What do you mean by definition?  Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming, perhaps wrongly, that your code includes a definition of a class called `Contractor` (just as it probably also includes a definition of a class called `Customer`). Could you show us the code for the `Contractor` class? -- But, from the error message you describe, it sounds as if maybe you *haven't* defined `Contractor` after all? If not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "Contractor cannot be resolved to a type" can mean

- you never wrote `class Contractor {...}` anywhere in your code
- Eclipse can't compile the whole project because of some build path issues (check the Problem view for build path errors)
- You forgot to import the type `Contractor`

Comment: When I force it to run a box pops up at the bottom that says: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: at SwimCalc.main(SwimCalc.java:558)            Line 558 is: public static void main(String[] args){

Comment: @Mike: In other words, if it won't compile then you can't run it. I think the error appears there because that's the point at which it first wants to use class `SwimCalc`, which is the one that hasn't compiled successfully.